# How to prevent Chrome (desktop) from activating portrait orientation with media selector?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have defined the following media selector within my CSS file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
       screen and (orientation: landscape)
```

This seems to be working fine with:

- Safari (on desktop/iphone/ipad)
- Firefox (on desktop)
- Internet Explorer (on desktop)

The desktop version of Chrome (v32 in my case) is switching from landscape to potrait when the browser window is resized below a certain width.

I was under the impression that desktop browsers were always landscape...

Is there a way to prevent Chrome from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have come up with an alternative solution which removes `orientation` from the media query altogether. This certainly isn't the most ideal solution since I am unable to apply specific styles of portrait orientations, but at least my page is usable on all of the devices which I have tested so far (desktop / iphone / ipad / kindle).

Inside the HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

The following selector then behaves exactly as intended since the above meta tag seems to take pixel density into consideration. Thus my page now looks correct on both regular and retina devices whilst continuing to behave properly in Chrome.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)
```

Answer (score 0):

The orientation could have been determined by comparing height to width. When the window `width` is smaller than its `height`, then the orientation would be considered portrait.

You could consider using `deviceorientation` to force accurate detection.

This demo illustrate the change from `landscape` to `portrait` using CSS orientation when the window height is higher than its width.
http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-orientation-styles/

Comment: The demo which you refer to exhibits the exact problem which I am experiencing with my own page. But your assumption holds true, when the window `width < height` it assumes portrait orientation which is very inconsistent behaviour when compared to the other major browsers. I do not follow your suggestion `deviceorientation` since I cannot find any documentation on this. Perhaps it is a JavaScript property?